# Photo Booth like backdrop effect in js

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

I'm looking for this particular effect, like green screen, but without a green screen :P

So, you set a camera at a fixed place, then you take one photo that will be the "green screen" so you doesn't really need one.

Any plugin, easy-way, to do it with canvas/webgl?

[Seriously.js](https://github.com/brianchirls/Seriously.js) is really nice, but only work's with a green background or a fixed color

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply check each pixel against the "green-screen" image and and if they're equal by some threshold make them transparent, or set them to what ever you want.

Depending on the resolution of the image you want to process, using a normal canvas(2D) will probably be too slow to do this.
If you would like to process video content in "realtime" you would need to go with a webgl approach with a simple glsl shader.

I dont know of any libraries doing this for you. Using the canvas approach should be fairly simple, using webgl you would need to learn some webgl using framebuffers, textures, basic geometry rendering(a library like threejs could handle the aforementioned) as well as some basic glsl.

Comment: Thanks :), I'm already doing this, here is an example [jsbin - testing chroma key](http://jsbin.com/fimisuhaqana/2/edit?js) - [Full Page Example](http://jsbin.com/fimisuhaqana/2) but I don't know how to improve it :(